# Standalone Eclipse Plugin for BlackBerry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

Where can I find a standalone eclipse plugin for blackberry? On the blackberry website in other to develop blackberry apps one has **to download a full eclipse and the plugin which is about 400MB**, that seems to me like a waste of resources since I already have an existing installation. Any pointers would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the BlackBerry java plugin to your existing eclipse via the [BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site](http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java). 
Here is the [official instruction link](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp) .

You should have  Eclipse 3.6+ version  and Java 2 SDK v6.0 Update 16+ .